# Is using Firefox while installing ill-advised?

Tags: system-installation, firefox

Okay, so, this is a silly question but I'm curious. When I'm installing Ubuntu, commonly, I'll skip to the end of the install dialog that shows up as it gives you some links you can click on. Those links open Firefox. I then browse Twitter and such while I'm waiting for my install.

Would I be better off sating my need for internet on my phone, or would this simply be like using it on a live install?

Comment: Nop. It's using the live system, won't influence the hard drive install, no harm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under most circumstances, browsing will have no significant effect upon installing Ubuntu. Most desktop systems have plenty of resources to both simultaneously.

If your network bandwidth is limited, then using some of that bandwidth for browsing might delay completion of the install by a few minutes.

Comment: Alright, that's what I figured, I just didn't know if there was some secret edge case that'd make Ubuntu explode. Thanks for assuaging my fears :P

Answer (score 1):

It's using the live system.

After opening Firefox, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to bring `tty1` up, use `xubuntu` as your username, then run:

```
df ~/.mozilla ~/.cache/mozilla
```

You'll see that the file are not really being written to drive.

Also:

```
mount | grep cow
```

Might be inserting to lookup.